# Docker run command is taking long to start container (20-30 mins)

Tags: docker

Here is my docker file ,

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl \
                                                python3-docker \
                                                wget \
                                                nginx
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Was able to build container successfully.

```bash
docker build -t ubuntunginx .
```

command to run container

```bash
docker run -it -p 80:80 ubuntunginx
```

Comment: it looks like you're running a different container than the one you just built and tagged. is that just an error in the question?

Comment: Its error while copy-paste , Thanks for letting.